# $(P \land \neg Q) \lor P \equiv P$ How is this proved using theorems?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have tried my best by using all possible ways but failed!

1. Commutative laws: $p \land q  \equiv q \land p$ and $p \lor q  \equiv q \lor p$
2. Associative laws: $(p \land q) \land r  \equiv p \land (q \land r)$ and $(p \lor q) \lor r  \equiv p \lor (q \lor r)$
3. Distributive laws: $p \land (q \lor r)  \equiv (p \land q) \lor (p \land r)$ and $p \lor (q \land r)  \equiv (p \lor q) \land (p \lor r)$
4. Identity laws: $p \land \top  \equiv p$ and $p \lor \bot  \equiv p$
5. Negation laws: $p \lor \neg p  \equiv \top$ and $p \land \neg p  \equiv \bot$
6. Double negative law: $\neg (\neg p)  \equiv p$
7. Idempotent laws: $p \land p  \equiv p$ and $p \lor p  \equiv p$
8. Universal bound laws: $p \lor \top \equiv \top$ and $p \land \bot \equiv \bot$
9. De Morgan’s laws: $\neg (p \land q)  \equiv \neg p \lor \neg q$ and $\neg (p \lor q)  \equiv \neg p \land \neg q$
10. Absorption laws: $p \lor (p \land q)  \equiv p$ and $p \land (p \lor q)  \equiv p$
11. Negations of $\top$ and $\bot$: $\neg \top  \equiv \bot$ and $\neg \bot  \equiv \top$

Comment: Whoops, misread it.  Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA.

Comment: but I asked how can we prove it using theorems?@MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be proved from the absorption law that you list with a variable substitution. Let $Q'=\neg Q$. Then by the absorption law, $(P \wedge Q') \vee P \equiv P$.

Comment: would it be correct?

Comment: @WaqadArshad yes. It follows pretty directly from the law that you listed and like someone else mentioned, you can check it with a truth table.

Comment: I know that this statement is true. all I am asking is that is it alright to write it this way?

Comment: You might want to substitute ~Q back in to rewrite it in its original form.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CyborgOctopus